# Invoking Read-Host cmdlet from within C# Custom Cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell, input, powershell-cmdlet

I'm writing a set of Powershell Cmdlets that require Oauth2 authentication. I currently am able to get to the point where a new browser window opens and the user copies out the Access Authentication Code to pass back to the cmdlets. However, this means I have to have a separate cmdlet that now accepts the Auth Code as input.

Is there any way to invoke the Read-Host? I've tried the [instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but despite being listed, [ReadHostCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.readhostcommand%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) isn't showing up under the Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands namespace, but something like [WhereObjectCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.whereobjectcommand%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is.

I've tried Console.ReadLine() but it is just ignored when running the Cmdlet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ReadHostCommand` is in the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands` namespace but you have to reference the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility.dll` assembly.

Comment: Ah the humbling answer that I should have thought of. Thank you for reminding me to check the basics!